# Why two similar functions are working in the different was in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to separate a string by ':' sign and then select the left-hand side of this separated string.
These functions are working well and I got the right output.

```
df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
df['title'].str.split(':').str[0]
```

Why this code gives an error

```
df['title'].split(':')[0]
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is giving an error because ``Series`` objects do not have an attribute ``split``. What makes you think they do?

Comment: They aren't that similar. The first applies `split` to each value in the series; the second tries to split the series itself. It's the same as the difference between `1 + some_list` and `[x + 1 for x in some_list]`.

Comment: I have not understood what you want. Are you asking us to solve the problem which you have already solved yourself?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using df["column"] you are getting a [series object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and the split() attributes is no applicable to that type of object. When using [df["column"].str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) you are actually accessing the values of the series and python is identifying them as strings, so you can preform string functions on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to split the entire title column of the data frame (which is the Series mentioned in the error message). What you want to do is apply a function to each row of the data frame, which you can do by calling apply on the data frame, like you have done in your first code block.